# Sitemap and object with multiple urls

Tags: python, django, sitemap

The normal way sitemap is used in Django is:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from schools.models import School


class SchoolSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "weekly"
    priority = 0.6

    def items(self):
        return School.objects.filter(status = 2)
```

and then in the model of School we define:

```
  def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('schools:school_about', kwargs={'school_id': self.pk})
```

In such implementation I have one About link for one school in sitemap.xml

The problem is that my school has multiple pages: About, Teachers, Pupils and others and I would like all of the to be rendered is sitemap.xml

What is the best approach to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can work with the fact that [`items` may return anything that can be passed to the other methods of a `Sitemap`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#django.contrib.sitemaps.Sitemap.items):

```
import itertools

class SchoolSitemap(Sitemap):
    # List method names from your objects that return the absolute URLs here
    FIELDS = ("get_absolute_url", "get_about_url", "get_teachers_url")

    changefreq = "weekly"
    priority = 0.6

    def items(self):
        # This will return you all possible ("method_name", object) tuples instead of the
        # objects from the query set. The documentation says that this should be a list 
        # rather than an iterator, hence the list() wrapper.
        return list(itertools.product(SchoolSitemap.FIELDS,
                                      School.objects.filter(status = 2)))

    def location(self, item):
        # Call method_name on the object and return its output
        return getattr(item[1], item[0])()
```

If the number and names of fields are not predetermined, I would go for a completely dynamic approach: Allow models to have a `get_sitemap_urls` method that returns a list of absolute URLs, and use a `Sitemap` that executes this method. That is, in the simplest case where you do not need to have access to the objects in the priority/changefreq/lastmod methods:

```
class SchoolSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "weekly"
    priority = 0.6

    def items(self):
        return list(
             itertools.chain.from_iterable(( object.get_sitemap_urls()
                                             for object in 
                                             School.objects.filter(status = 2)))
        )

    def location(self, item):
        return item
```

Comment: Thank you! You solution is working however I have changed it to fit my project because I have variable number of FIELDS for each model object.

Comment: Good to hear. I'll amend the answer with how I'd solve the variable number of links case.

Comment: thank you one more time! I made it in the same way with object function and normal loops. you approach looks more elegant.